# Why is the schema name necessary here and how to compile without it

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oracle18c

I'm working on an Oracle Forms 11g application linked with an Oracle 18c database and I stumbled upon a strange error when compiling my form.

Here's a snippet to illustrate the problem (I changed the identifiers name but it doesn't matter):

```
PROCEDURE SOME_PROCEDURE(...) IS
  v_arg1 relation.c_arg1%type;
  v_arg2 relation.c_arg2%type;
  v_arg3 relation.c_arg3%type;
BEGIN

  SELECT r.c_arg1, r.c_arg2, r.c_arg3
    INTO v_arg1, v_arg2, v_arg3
    FROM relation r
   WHERE ...

  -- Some more code ...

END;
```

When I'm compiling, the error I get is :

```
Compilation errors on SOME_PROCEDURE:
PL/SQL ERROR 302 at line 2, column 19
component 'C_ARG1' must be declared
PL/SQL ERROR 0 at line 2, column 10
Item ignored
PL/SQL ERROR 302 at line 3, column 19
component 'C_ARG2' must be declared
PL/SQL ERROR 0 at line 3, column 10
Item ignored
PL/SQL ERROR 302 at line 4, column 19
component 'C_ARG3' must be declared
PL/SQL ERROR 0 at line 4, column 10
Item ignored
```

`relation` here is a table name and is causing the problem. If, for testing purposes, I pick another table and field name, the code compiles fine e.g. `v_arg1 other_table.other_field%type;`.

I figured maybe `relation` is a reserved keyword (even though I couldn't find anything in the documentation about this specific keyword, yikes), so I tried to put the schema name `admin` before the table name:

```
PROCEDURE SOME_PROCEDURE(...) IS
  v_arg1 admin.relation.c_arg1%type;
  v_arg2 admin.relation.c_arg2%type;
  v_arg3 admin.relation.c_arg3%type;
BEGIN
```

And it works just fine. Now this is a problem, because `admin` is not a fixed name and will change because multiple schemas are used for multiple purposes ie development, testing, production, etc.

This is where I'm stuck. I don't know how to do this the "right" way: because the %type is a VARCHAR2 with some length, I'll use something large such as VARCHAR2(100) and hopefully it downcasts without errors in the future.

My question is, is it possible to come up with a way to reference this table without specifying the schema?

This is for my work, I don't have much freedom in changing the table/schema name, etc.

Thank you

Comment: Without a schema name, Oracle looks in the current schema first. If there is a `relation` table in the current schema, and that table doesn't have the columns you referenced, that would cause that issue. If there is no such table in the current schema, then Oracle will look for a synonym. Again, if the synonym is for a table that doesn't have those columns, you would get that error. Those are the first two places I would look. ("Current" schema means schema from which the procedure is executed.)

Comment: Basically you are saying you have a procedure in schema `A` and wants to refrence a table `T` that is either in schema `B` or `C`or `D`. You'll have to define some environment dependent solution using a `synonym`or a `view` that will tell you that the table in the *current environment* is in the schema say `B`.  This will allow you to have the procedure identical in all environments. `Synonym` is the probably more *lightweight* solution

Comment: @mathguy : the table and these columns definitely exist, I'll investigate for synonyms thanks :)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber : thanks for the comment, I will keep this in mind